# Why "req.user" always empty in the /user/me controller after validation with sails-auth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I'm currently getting started with Sails.js, and I want to add user accounts to my toy app, so I installed the "sails-auth" package that creates a Passport-based user authentication system. I can create new users by sending `POST /user`, and I can sign in with `POST /auth/local`.

The documentation says:

> Authenticate with the local strategy via a POST to /auth/local with params identifier (email) and password). This will also create a session. See passport.local for more.

However, when I try to `GET /user/me`, which routes to a controller action that should return the current user in the session, the page instead gives an empty response. Why is this happening? Is there some kind of configuration step that I'm missing?

By the way, I haven't changed or messed around with the sails-auth package. It's still completely new; the "me" action looks like this:

```
  me: function (req, res) {
    res.ok(req.user);
  }
```

**EDIT**: I've found a temporary workaround by searching the issues in the sails-auth repo. Instead of getting a user object from `req.user`, you can get a string user ID from `req.session.passport.user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `me` action as written is only going to return whatever you are passing in as the user param. Sails builds on top of Express.js so `req` is the request from the browser and `res` is the response to the browser.

Most likely you are sending the data to your `me` action in the `req` body which is why your response is blank, simply put, `req.user` is empty so the response is empty. In that case you would access it with `req.body.user`, you could also try `var user = req.params();`

For debugging and just generally getting a feel for how the `req` and `res` objects are structured I suggest you always start sails (in development, never in production) with the `verbose` flag.
`sails lift --verbose`

Then you can do this:

```
me: function(req, res){
   sails.log.verbose(req);
   res.ok(req.user);
}
```

And have it print out the entire req object so you know what's in `req.user`.

Typically though you would do a database lookup as the `user` param would be an id. Which means your `me` function might look (something, obviously depending on your dbc it might be pretty different) like:

```
me: function(req, res){
    var userId = req.body.user;
    User.find({'user_id': userId}.exec(function(err, user){
        if(err){
            //tell peeps there was an error
        }else{
            res.ok(user);
        }
    });
}
```

Best debugging for routes and for the request object:

```
    '/*' : function(req, res, next) {
        sails.log.verbose("method: ", req.method, "\n body: ", req.body, "\n url:", req.url);
        next();
    },
```

Just paste that at the start of your routes module.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe the "user" object isn't a parameter (from searching around in the source). It's something that's set by the callback in the AuthController when it does stuff with Passport.js (see image http://i.imgur.com/WySYqRW.png).

Additionally, how do I edit the source code of the "me" action? It's part of an npm module. When I last tried to edit it (adding logging), the logging messages didn't show up.

Comment: @EricZhang Hmm, maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly, so you didn't write the `me` function?  but you have a route in your routing table that directs to it?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't write the `me` function. The route is just from a blueprint action (UserController/me). I think that if I were to turn them off, then I would have to make a route to the `me` function. Sorry if it wasn't clear!

Comment: @EricZhang, and I see where your coming from thinking that req.user is supposed to contain your user, but each `req` from the client is it's own object and has it's own state, so a call to authenticate, and then a *separate* call to `/me` is going to generate two different `req` objects.

Comment: if you paste that last pit of code at the start of your routes module, then lift with the `--verbose` flag you can see all sorts of things about the `req` object in your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for that bit of code; I ran it and I got a null req.body and a null req.user. Does this mean that the sails-auth module is completely broken? If so, how would I circumvent this problem?

Comment: Would a possible fix be to simply store the user ID as a session variable?

Comment: @EricZhang, sorry went home for the night, I wouldn't say that sails-auth is broken per-sey but... when I implemented my auth a year ago I kept my passport and sails layers pretty simple, then implemented my session using a mongo-store as I found theirs needlessly complicated to set up and fairly buggy/restrictive.